# Disable request logging via HttpClient for single url

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpclient

I have an own library that exposes health-check implementation via http client:

In StartupExtensions in my library:

```
services.AddHttpClient(Consts.HealthChecksHttpClientName, c =>
{
     c.BaseAddress = new Uri(options.BaseUrl);
     c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "close");
});
```

How can I turn off default logging for the health-check url?

I KNOW I can disable all logs:

```
services.RemoveAll<IHttpMessageHandlerBuilderFilter>();
```

I don't want to remove all logs from all of http clients that do not belongs to the library - just want to disable only single url for my http client.

Is the way to override for it only for specified HttpClient?
I do not want to use `Serilog` - only with standard `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logging filter should be depend on how we make use of `HttpClient`. For example, using like this

```
using var weatherHttpClient = new HttpClient()
// make using here
```

AFAIK, this case would be impossible to separate logging from `HttpClient`.

If we using `HttpClient` via DI, we could make a filter like this.

```
// Register with DI. I'm just a fan of named HttpClient, use your register as wished
services.AddHttpClient(nameof(WeatherService), cfg =>
{
    cfg.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    cfg.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.openweathermap.org");
});

// Using WeatherService class: 
private readonly HttpClient _httpClient; 

public WeatherService(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
{
    _httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient(nameof(WeatherService));
}

// We can create a logging Filter on Program.cs like
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureLogging(logging  =>
            {
                logging.AddFilter((_, category, _) => !category.StartsWith($"System.Net.Http.HttpClient.{nameof(WeatherService)}"));
            })
```

Register as `services.AddHttpClient<WeatherService>` would result the same category name to filter.

But I still feel it some way cumbersome... of not using `Serilog`, could you share the reason why say no to that ?